# psycopg2 cannot find any tables after connection

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I can connect to my database, but psycopg2 fails to find any of my tables. The following will error trying to get my users:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='pdb' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='password'")
except:
    print 'failed to connect'

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(""" SELECT * from Users """)
rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row[0]

#Error:
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * from Users 

# This also fails
cur.execute("""SELECT * from pdb.Users """)
```

If I do:

```
cur.execute(""" SELECT * from pg_database """)

# Outputs
template1
template0
postgres
pdb
```

In my admin panel, pdb shows a bunch of tables, one of them being `Users`, so I'm not sure why psycopg2 can't find it.

Here's a printout from psql for `pdb`:

```
               List of relations
 Schema |        Name        | Type  |  Owner   
--------+--------------------+-------+----------
 public | Companies          | table | postgres
 public | Users              | table | postgres
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your table names `Users` and `Companies` both start with a capitalized letter. PostgreSQL will convert all identifiers to lower case (by default), as you can see from the error message:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "users" does not exist
```

Where `users` is written in all lower case. This is needed if you wish to strictly follow the SQL standard (as PostgreSQL is renowned for). You can solve this in two ways:

Solve it in your database:

Adhere to a common convention and rename your *tables* to be all lowercase.

Solve it in your code:

Quote your identifiers (your table name in this case) so PostgreSQL will leave them untouched:

```
cur.execute(""" SELECT * from "Users" """)
```

Comment: You saved my day. I didn't know that "standard" and, to be honest, it's weird. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue also usually happens when you are connected to wrong database. In my case i was connected to wrong database
Below is my code to connect using psycopg2 library

```
import psycopg2
try:
            src_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={} user={} host=localhost password={}".format(self.src_db, self.src_db, self.src_url ,self.src_pwd))
            if src_conn:
                src_curr = src_conn.cursor()
                print("Cursor found",src_curr)
                src_curr.execute("select * from product_template")
                recs = src_curr.fetchall()
                print(recs)
            else:
                print("Cursor not found")
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
```