# django model missing when accessing with psycopg2

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I've been building a django app and the `models.py` includes a few models:

- `Customer`
- `Error`
- `Record`

When I run `python3 manage.py shell` I have no errors with:

```
From myapp.models import Customer, Error, Record
records = Record.objects.all()
print(len(records))
# the same works if I run the query for Customer, Error, etc.
```

However, if I try to connect using `psycopg2` I'm finding that some tables are not accessible.

```
cur.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select relname from pg_class where relkind='r' and relname !~ '^(pg_|sql_)';")
print cursor.fetchall()

[('django_migrations',),
 ('django_content_type',),
 ('django_admin_log',),
 ('auth_group_permissions',),
 ('auth_group',),
 ('auth_user_groups',),
 ('auth_permission',),
 ('auth_user_user_permissions',),
 ('django_session',),
 ('my_app_contactme',),
 ('my_app_employee',),
 ('auth_user',),
 ('Error',),
 ('my_app_blogpost_category',),
 ('Customer',),
 ('Record',)]

 cur.execute("SELECT * from Customer")

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ProgrammingError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-38-3532e0e20e34> in <module>()
 ----> 1 cur.execute("SELECT * from Customer")

 ProgrammingError: relation "customer" does not exist
 LINE 1: SELECT * from Customer
```

I can't figure out why `Customer`, `Error` and `Record` are causing issues with accessing via psycopg2

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the answer here - [psycopg2 cannot find any tables after connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434633/psycopg2-cannot-find-any-tables-after-connection)

```
cur.execute(""" SELECT * from "Customer" """)
```